# Image Cacheing in iOS Swift

Tags: ios

I have a function to download image from a URL. I am checking if the image is already found in the cached images, if found, I need to terminate the task if the image is found.
In this if condition, even if a match is found, the program still continues to the task.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't post images, post text. You have to add a `return` statement right after the first `completion(result)` line. As you must return a `URLSessionDataTask` I recommend to do the cache check somewhere else. And never `sleep`, not even for test purpose.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.